# Why does exim4 accept my message although I tell it shouldn't (via require_files)?

Tags: exim

I use exim for virtual domains. I created the following router:

```
domains_virtual:
  debug_print = "R: domains_virtual for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = accept
  domains = /etc/exim4/domains_virtual.txt
  require_files = /var/mail/virtual/$domain_data/$local_part_data
  transport = virtual_mailbox
  cannot_route_message = Unknown virtual user $local_part@$domain
```

I send a test mail to `oehtgczb@example.local` which should not be accepted:

```
# ls -la /var/mail/virtual/example.local
insgesamt 30
drwxrwsr-x 3 root mailuser  4 10. Sep 07:34 .
drwxrwsr-x 4 root mailuser  4 10. Sep 06:20 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 root mailuser 92 10. Sep 06:26 .aliases
drwxrws--- 5 root mailuser  5  9. Mär 2011  ouzncwso
#
```

Yet the message is accepted and exim creates the maildir for `oehtgczb`!

Why? How can I tell it otherwise?

EDIT: Yes, the router is invoked:

```
# exim4 -bt oehtgczb@example.local
R: domains_virtual_forward for oehtgczb@example.local
R: domains_virtual for oehtgczb@example.local
oehtgczb@example.local
  router = domains_virtual, transport = virtual_mailbox
```

This is the log if I do a SMTP session to localhost:

```
2021-09-10 09:38:50.990 [32472] SMTP connection from [127.0.0.1]:57196 I=[127.0.0.1]:25 (TCP/IP connection count = 2)
2021-09-10 09:39:27.136 [34113] 1mOb84-0008sD-82 SA: Debug: SAEximRunCond expand returned: ''
2021-09-10 09:39:27.137 [34113] 1mOb84-0008sD-82 SA: Action: Not running SA because SAEximRunCond expanded to false (Message-Id: 1mOb84-0008sD-82). From <test@localhost> (host=localhost [127.0.0.1]) for oehtgczb@example.local
2021-09-10 09:39:27.161 [34113] 1mOb84-0008sD-82 <= test@localhost H=localhost (x) [127.0.0.1]:57196 I=[127.0.0.1]:25 P=smtp S=477 M8S=0 RT=6s id*=E1mOb84-0008sD-82@example.local from <test@localhost> for oehtgczb@example.local
2021-09-10 09:39:27.182 [34120] 1mOb84-0008sD-82 Warning: Tainted '/var/mail/virtual/example.local/oehtgczb' (file or directory name for virtual_mailbox transport) not permitted
2021-09-10 09:39:27.201 [34119] 1mOb84-0008sD-82 => oehtgczb <oehtgczb@example.local> F=<test@localhost> P=<test@localhost> R=domains_virtual T=virtual_mailbox S=596 QT=6s DT=0.021s
2021-09-10 09:39:27.202 [34119] 1mOb84-0008sD-82 Completed QT=6s
2021-09-10 09:39:28.899 [34113] SMTP connection from localhost (x) [127.0.0.1]:57196 I=[127.0.0.1]:25 closed by QUIT
```

Comment: You need to address this, I think, `Warning: Tainted '/var/mail/virtual/example.local/oehtgczb' (file or directory name for virtual_mailbox transport) not permitted`

Answer (score 0):

I think I have a solution. Use `local_parts` instead of `require_files`:

```
domains_virtual:
  debug_print = "R: domains_virtual for $local_part@$domain"
  driver = accept
  domains = /etc/exim4/domains_virtual.txt
  local_parts = dsearch;/var/mail/virtual/$domain_data
  transport = virtual_mailbox
  cannot_route_message = Unknown virtual user $local_part@$domain
```